# Unique Start and End Effective Date Scenario

Tags: sql-server, date

Okay, so I have an sql query that I run on a weekly basis that now needs to be ran on a monthly basis. In the query I have a start effective date and an end effective date for the date range the report should pull. Now what I want to do is a formula for the start and end date.

The start effective date I want to be previous month from today's date and then the last Monday of the previous month.

The end effective date I want to be the max modified date from my product details table.

I know what I am looking for but I am unsure how to write this in code? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    declare @dt datetime
set @dt=GETDATE()
select DATEADD(WEEK,DATEDIFF(WEEK,0,DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DAY,dateadd(m,-1,GETDATE())),dateadd(m,-1,GETDATE()))), 0) StartDate
```

Comment: you want start date as previous month first monday, am i right?

Comment: Thnx. Updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @Today date = convert(date, getdate());
DECLARE @Monday tinyint = 1;
DECLARE @LastDayOfMonth date = DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Today), 0));
DECLARE @LastWeekDayOfMonth int = datepart(weekday,DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Today), 0)));

SELECT DATEADD(d, @Monday-@LastWeekDayOfMonth+1, @LastDayOfMonth) AS LastMonday
```

Comment: You are aware that this depends on DATEFIRST setting?

Comment: That is why I defined the variable @monday... but thinking of it, you are right... might need modified/additional calculation... but just in case Monday is the first day of the week, this should work. ;-)

Comment: Which unf doesn't help, because it's the DATEPART function which is affected: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: Then it should look something like this:

DECLARE @LastWeekDayOfMonth int = ((datepart(weekday,DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Today), 0))) + @@DateFirst - 1 - 1) % 7) + 1;

In this case the last +1 (after doing the substraction) has to be removed